# How to detect an selected image from camera preview using tensor flow in Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, image-recognition

I want to create an Android application that will identify an selected image (gallery or whatever) from camera preview using image recognition in TensorFlow. Is it possible to convert the selected image as an object & identify that image object from camera preview.

Thanks

Comment: "convert the selected image as an object", what do you exactly by this? Try describing your problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below example available in Tensorflow site on how to do object detections in Android

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android

If this is not what you are looking for, kindy give an elaborative description about the issue you are trying to resolve.